# Bottom Bracket Creaking

Tags: mountain-bike, bottom-bracket, creak

I have a 1993 Rockhopper frame that I'm riding as a singlespeed.  I have some creaking around my bottom bracket.  I've just recently stripped and painted the frame, and there wasn't anything suspicious around the bottom bracket shell.  The bottom bracket is a sealed cartridge type.  I've had some problems with the nuts that hold the chainring onto the crank coming loose, so I'm wondering whether that's the source of the noise.  What is the best way to go about determining what's causing the noise?

Comment: Is that road or mountain, perhaps add some more tags.

Comment: @Johan: Rockhopper is a MTB from specialized

Comment: Can you describe more about how you reproduce the noise? Only while pedaling, only when stand pedaling, only when putting pressure to the pedals versus just spinning, etc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I've had some problems with the nuts that hold the chainring onto the crank coming loose, so I'm wondering whether that's the source of the noise.

It is very likely. It often requires a special tool to tighten firmly, but tightening it will either eliminate a "creak candidate" ... or the noise itself :)

Answer (score 2):

creaking is often also attributable to loose cranks. you'll want to check this sooner rather than later, because loose cranks will round your bottom bracket spindle, and the problem will get worse faster.

Answer (score 1):

I had a creaking sound that I couldn't locate - thought a pedal was loose or something. Turns out it was the bottom bracket failing. It eventually cracked through, and I had a fun ride home before I could replace it. Not sure if there's a simple way to check that, without pulling the cranks off and looking...

Comment: One of the other questions on here (I couldn't spot it just) has a reply which suggests removing the cranks and turning the spindle by hand. If it's crunchy etc then it's failing.