# Bike creaking (possibly pedals?)

Tags: pedals, creak

When I pedal fairly hard there is a creak coming from the bottom of the bike. I have read several other questions which talk about a similar thing however my situation is slightly different:

The creaking stops when I flip the right hand pedal 180 degrees.

Should I just change the pedals to fix this?

To be clear I believe this is a problem with the pedals.

---

**Related questions dealing with other sources of creaking from the bottom bracket, crankset, or pedal area:**

- [Bottom Bracket Creaking](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/33/bottom-bracket-creaking?rq=1)
- [Creaking from cranks/spindle. How to fix?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/124/creaking-from-cranks-spindle-how-to-fix?rq=1)

Comment: I've had the same issue. Replacing pedals fixed the problem for me. If the pedals are from metal, and the pieces of metal are attached to each other with screws, you can try to tighten them before replacing.

Comment: Excellent, I think they are, I will go try that now. Thanks.

Comment: before you go and buy new pedals, try taking them off and giving the whole region a clean & lube. Could be you'll need new parts anyway, but you might find that some tlc will save you some cash.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creaking from cranks/spindle. How to fix?](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/124/creaking-from-cranks-spindle-how-to-fix)

Comment: @RoboKaren This isn't a duplicate. It's clearly a pedal issue.

Comment: I checked the screws and on one side there was one really lose one, and one missing, so I'm sure that's what it was. If you make that an answer I'll gladly accept it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Got it, I edited it in as a "related questions" and will remove my close flag. Feel free to revert if it goes against authorial intent.

Comment: Confirmed, tightening the screws made the creaking stop. Eric's answer was correct. If it's not posted today Ill make it an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what was described, I.E the creaking going away when the pedal in question was flipped 180 degrees I think we can assume that it is the pedals which are at fault. 
When using metal pedals there are often screws attaching the outer rim to the center. These may have become lose and just require tightening with a screwdriver.

Answer (score 0):

I could tell you more accurately if I were riding with you and could hear the noise and where it came from. But, I can tell you these things for certain:

Clean and lube your pedal bearings. Do not skimp and just add some oil. Also make sure your pedals and crankarms are tightened to the *correct* recommended torque.

Do not delay before applying these maintenance measures. I say "do not delay" because the cause *could* be that the crankarms are not torqued down properly. This is not likely, but it is possible, and if it is the reason? Then you can ruin the crankset within a few miles of riding. That's right - ruin - to the point of a crankarm or the crank spider cracking and eventually breaking. If it cracks you will see it happening - and it won't be sudden - so in that way it is not unsafe, ok? But it will be relatively expensive to fix.

So the first thing you need to do is to make sure the moving parts involved (pedals, crankarms, bottom bracket) have proper maintenance and lubrication. Your problem is likely somewhere in there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As stated in the comments it was lose screws on the pedal housing. I'm pretty glad that I didn't disassemble stuff only to find out that I didn't have to. I have added the correct answer as the original poster of the answer failed to do so. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: Cool! Often such things are something surprisingly simple. Glad you found it!